# Why is the optimizer not using the clustering index on my table?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, execution-plan, postgresql-14

I have this table

```
                     Table "public.lineitem"
     Column      |     Type      | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+---------------+-----------+----------+---------
 l_orderkey      | integer       |           |          | 
 l_partkey       | integer       |           |          | 
 l_suppkey       | integer       |           |          | 
 l_linenumber    | integer       |           |          | 
 l_quantity      | integer       |           |          | 
 l_extendedprice | numeric(12,2) |           |          | 
 l_discount      | numeric(12,2) |           |          | 
 l_tax           | numeric(12,2) |           |          | 
 l_returnflag    | character(1)  |           |          | 
 l_linestatus    | character(1)  |           |          | 
 l_shipdate      | date          |           |          | 
 l_commitdate    | date          |           |          | 
 l_receiptdate   | date          |           |          | 
 l_shipinstruct  | character(25) |           |          | 
 l_shipmode      | character(10) |           |          | 
 l_comment       | character(44) |           |          | 
 l_partsuppkey   | character(20) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "l_shipdate_c_idx" btree (l_shipdate) CLUSTER
    "l_shipmode_h_idx" hash (l_shipdate)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "lineitem_l_orderkey_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (l_orderkey) REFERENCES orders(o_orderkey)
    "lineitem_l_partkey_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (l_partkey) REFERENCES part(p_partkey)
    "lineitem_l_partsuppkey_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (l_partsuppkey) REFERENCES partsupp(ps_partsuppkey)
    "lineitem_l_suppkey_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (l_suppkey) REFERENCES supplier(s_suppkey)
```

and this query:

```
explain analyze select
    l_returnflag,
    l_linestatus,
    sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty,
    sum(l_extendedprice) as sum_base_price,
    sum(l_extendedprice*(1 - l_discount)) as sum_disc_price,
    sum(l_extendedprice*(1 - l_discount)*(1 + l_tax)) as sum_charge,
    avg(l_quantity) as avg_qty,
    avg(l_extendedprice) as avg_price,
    avg(l_discount) as avg_disc,
    count(*) as count_order
from
    lineitem
where
    l_shipdate<='31/08/1998'
GROUP by
    l_returnflag,
    l_linestatus
ORDER by
    l_returnflag,
    l_linestatus
```

returning this query plan:

```
"Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=2631562.25..2631564.19 rows=6 width=212) (actual time=28624.012..28624.466 rows=4 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: l_returnflag, l_linestatus"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=2631562.25..2631563.65 rows=12 width=212) (actual time=28623.998..28624.442 rows=12 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=2630562.23..2630562.24 rows=6 width=212) (actual time=28620.633..28620.633 rows=4 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: l_returnflag, l_linestatus"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB"
"              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB"
"              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB"
"              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=2630562.03..2630562.15 rows=6 width=212) (actual time=28620.607..28620.611 rows=4 loops=3)"
"                    Group Key: l_returnflag, l_linestatus"
"                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB"
"                    Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB"
"                    Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB"
"                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on lineitem  (cost=0.00..1707452.35 rows=24616258 width=24) (actual time=0.549..19028.353 rows=19701655 loops=3)"
"                          Filter: (l_shipdate <= '1998-08-31'::date)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 293696"
"Planning Time: 0.374 ms"
"Execution Time: 28624.523 ms"
```

- Why is the optimizer preferring the sequential scan over `lineitem` table instead of using `l_shipdate_c_idx`? Should I drop it?

Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 14.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29), 64-bit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter

```
l_shipdate<='31/08/1998'
```

Is not very selective, we can see from the plan that it was responsible for removing only 293,696 rows and it ended up needing to use 19,701,655. If it was to use an index to read those rows one by one it would probably have been much slower than the sequential scan of the table.

> Should I drop it?

If this is the only query you are running and the only filter being used, then probably. Otherwise, there's not enough information to go on. The index would probably be useful if you wanted to see the rows for 1 particular day. The index might be better off with some additional columns in it. Impossible to say without knowing your application.

Comment: This query belongs to TPC-H benchmark and you can see those queries on the internet

Comment: @tail I'm not expecting you to share all the queries, I'm telling you how you can evaluate it yourself.